# Delete the next $item in cart (laravel crinsane)

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I need ability when delete one $item from cart to delete also previous or the next item, so :

```
Cart::remove()
```

To remove an item for the cart, you'll again need the rowId. This rowId you simply pass to the `remove()` method and it will remove the item from the cart.

```
$rowId = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709';

Cart::remove($rowId);
```

this is from documentation.

How I can delete item with `$rowId = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709';` and the next item with unknown rowID ?

Comment: How did you get the first ID to know that you need to delete it? Pass the second one the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Since your primary key looks like it's not auto increment, the only thing you have left to know the next/previous items is `created_at` or whatever you called the creation time in your database.

Before deleting any time, get the next one first, because once deleted, you don't have access to that item anymore, thus you don't what came next. Not sure if you are using a package or not, but doing `Cart::remove($rowid)` means that somehow you have a way to know the `$rowid`. If you could do something like

```
$itemToDelete = Cartitem::where('row_id',$rowId)->first();//get the item to be deleted 

//Next item 
$next = Cartitem::where('created_at', '>', $itemToDelete->created_at)
->orderBy('created_at')
->first();

//Previous item 
$previous = Cartitem::where('created_at', '<', $itemToDelete->created_at)
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->first();
```

This should help you understand how to play with your tables to get previous and next items.